# How to create SSRS 2008r2 rdl using VS 2008 BIDS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have installed SSRS 2008 and SSRS 2008r2 on my machine.

When I create a new Report Server Project , I also changed the TargetServerVersion to match SQL Server 2008 R2 and made sure that it is pointing to correct report server ( 2008 r2 ).

After doing this when I create a blank report and try to check view code , It has same schema as the rdls created for SSRS 2008

http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition

Is that ok ?

I know that SSRS  2008r2 supports new element called ReportSection so it must have new schema to support it.

How do I know that the rdl created by VS2008 is of SSRS 2008 or SSRS 2008r2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct to look at the schema version but the schema version will NOT change until you put a feature in the report that is specific to 2008r2.
As a test case make a quick report with the configuration targeting R2 with a very simple tablix based off a simple SQL statement.
On my machine this generated a rdl file with a 2008 schema.

```
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition">
```

Now add an entry under the PageName attribute.

On my machine the schema changed to the following:

```
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:cl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">
```

I believe once you add an attribute that converts the rdl to 2008r2 you will not be able to edit it with the "non" r2 2008 BIDS.